# Lost EU driving license in Portugal

Tags: driving-license, portugal

I'm trying to find the official web site for getting a new EU driving license that was lost. I can only find this page but it says to bring my old license which I do not have:

http://www.imtonline.pt/index.php/troca-de-titulos-conducao-estrangeiros/driving-licence-exchange109/9-uncategorised/2313-1st-situation-24

Where can I find this information?

Comment: The EU does not issue driver's licenses; its individual member states do.  To replace a lost license it is necessary to approach the licensing authority of the country that issued the license.  Was the license issued by Portugal?

Comment: No. It was issued in The Netherlands. And I've ordered that document from them. But I live in Portugal and need to apply for it here.

Comment: @dan-klasson I'm in the same situation. How did it go?

Answer (score 1):

In most countries a driving license will only be reissued where it was originaly issued or at your present main residence.

If you lose any official document, you should report this to the local police.

They should then issue a **theft report**.

Depending on the local laws, the theft report may be sufficient to actualy drive back to your own country.

You should look at a automobil club of your own country to see what advice they give.

Below is the advice from the German automobil club ADAC.

---

**Sources**:

- [Was tun bei Führerscheinverlust im Ausland? / Der ADAC erklärt, an wen sich ... | Presseportal](https://www.presseportal.de/pm/7849/3366397)

> Wer ohne Führerscheindokument zurück nach Deutschland fährt, riskiert kein Strafverfahren wegen Fahrens ohne Fahrerlaubnis. Der Führerschein dokumentiert nur das Bestehen einer Fahrerlaubnis, und diese bleibt nach dem Verlust bestehen. Allerdings kann in Deutschland ein Verwarnungsgeld von zehn Euro für das Nichtmitführen verhängt werden. Nach einem Diebstahl ist es daher empfehlenswert, die **polizeiliche Diebstahlsanzeige** mitzuführen, weil dann manchmal von einem Bußgeld abgesehen wird.
>
> > Anyone who drives back to Germany without a driver's license document does not risk criminal proceedings for driving without a driver's license. The driver's license only documents the existence of a driving license, and this remains in existence after loss.  However, in Germany a warning fine of ten euros can be imposed for not carrying an item with you. After a theft, it is therefore advisable to carry the **police theft report** with you, because then sometimes a fine is waived.
>
> Wer ohne Führerschein mehrere Grenzen passiert, muss eventuell mit einem Bußgeld des jeweiligen Landes rechnen, weil er das Dokument nicht mitführt.
>
> > Anyone who crosses several borders without a driver's license may have to expect a fine from the respective country because they do not have the document with them.

Comment: I'm not trying to drive home. I live in Portugal

Comment: @dan-klasson Then, with the **theft report**, go to the office meantioned in your link. The report will explain the reason why you can't bring your lost driving licence. If you have a copy of the original, bring that to. Please add that you live in Portugal to your question.